# How to determine which platform the current app is running on in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I need to offer slightly different app logic depending on the deployment platform my LibGDX app is running on, i.e. Desktop or Android, etc., **does the LibGDX API offer a method of identifying the current runtime platform?**

This [post, "abstracting platform specific code in libGDX"](http://siondream.com/blog/games/abstracting-platform-specific-code-in-libgdx) offers a solution of sorts, I'm just wondering if there is something directly available in the API itself (?).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could potentially use [`Application#getType()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Application.html#getType%28%29), which will return one of the values defined by [`Application.ApplicationType`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Application.ApplicationType.html):

- Android
- Applet
- Desktop
- iOS
- WebGL

Comment: Another way to do it is to use an interface in the shared code section and resolve it differently in each of the sub projects.

Answer (score 17):

If people are having trouble figuring out where you actually get the ApplicationType from, it's accessed from:

```
Gdx.app.getType()
```

And for a working example this would do:

```
if(Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.iOS) {
    //Do awesome stuff for iOS here
}
```